# How to recycle bitmap which is drawn in CustomDrawable?(android)

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap, recycle

Jpardogo's GoogleProgressBar is cool. A CustomDrawable is setted in ProgressBar.
So I decided to learn to create a CustomDrawable.

I use canvas.drawBitmap() in Drawable.draw() because I want a colorful image instead of painted line.
The question is :
I don't know when to recycle the bitmap. An OutOfMemory will occured if I leave it.
How do Android recycle views and their Drawable? Is there any callback which I can use?
In the situation, how could I recycle the bitmap?

Sorry for my English.